# MySQL WHERE Condition on integer field returning incorrect values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a problem with MySQL returning the incorrect result when applying a WHERE condition to an integer field with a string value.

```
CREATE TABLE `people` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `people` (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Bob'),
    (2, 'Sally'),
    (3, 'Jim');
```

Now when I run the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM people
WHERE id = '1-abcd';
```

My result set is:

```
id  name
1   Bob
```

MySQL appears to be truncating the string value '1-abcd' to '1' behind the scenes as soon as it hits a non-integral character (in the conversion from a string to INT).

You're probably wondering why this matters. I'm trying to fix a site for a PCI compliance scan. The scan thinks the URI '/some/page?id=102-1' is allowing some form of sequel injection, but in reality it's showing the same content at '/some/page?id=102'.

This is not an issue in one place. It is an issue all over the place, and it's a fairly large system. Is there some way to rectify this on the MySQL end of things, so it no longer mistakenly judges the two values to be equivalent? I looked at the documentation for SQL modes, but didn't see anything regarding this circumstance.

UPDATE: I filed a dispute with the company that produced the scan, which they accepted, so I'm no longer in the woods. But it is disappointing that there's apparently no way to configure the casting behavior of MySQL from a string to INT in this case. (You can, but only for INSERTs and UPDATEs.)

Comment: Confused about the question is `MYSQL` doing what it is supposed too? Is the "My result set" the desired result or do you want something else? Or are you asking how to get the query to only register the `1` and not the `1-0`?

Comment: What do you want it to do then? evaluate a 0 id that does not exist in sql? Or using another example you want it to evalute `3-5` getting all the ids from 3 to 5?

Comment: @Jay No, I want it to return 0 results. There is now row with the ID '1-0'. But MySQL is converting '1-0' to 1 behind the scenes.

Comment: Why can't you the logic the the governing language. Say php above the sql? just remove anything if trailing a int?

Comment: @Jay Because that would require a lot of work. It's a large system. In any case, I filed a dispute with the company that produced the scan. Because the system isn't actually vulnerable to SQL injection, they accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

What happens that MySQL type-casts the string literal value to an integer, and when it does that it starts from the left of the string and as soon as it reaches a character that cannot be considered part of a number, it strips out everything from that point on. So 1-0 gives output matching to 1. To do this you can use `cast`. I am not 100% sure about the syntax but it is like this:

```
select * from people 
where id =
  (
  case when ISNUMERIC( '1-0' ) 
  then cast ('1-0' as int)
  else null
  end  )
```

What this will do is that if it is an numeric value then it will return the correct matching row or else not.

**Edit:**

The above query seems to be of MSSQL/Oracle and would not work with MySQL. For MySQL you can use RegExp. I have never use one but you can find more details here:

http://mysqlhints.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-find-out-if-entire-string-is.html

http://www.ash.burton.fm/blogs/2010/12/quick-tip-mysql-equivalent-of-isnumeric

http://www.justskins.com/forums/how-to-use-isnumeric-137604.html

Comment: I appreciate the reply, but this doesn't fix my problem. The issue is that I don't want to go through the whole system and fix the problem everywhere. I was hoping there is a setting so that MySQL won't cast '1-0' as 1.

Comment: There are settings like `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` but they only work on `UPDATE` and `INSERT` not on `SELECT`. More details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html

Comment: Surely this is a bug, as you would expect this to fail completely given the danger of an accidental update